# Portable gaming notebook that has to be bought in the months december 2016 and january 2017

Tags: laptop

I am a freelance programmer. I am going to be in Switzerland in January, so I can buy my hardware there.

I would like to purchase a gaming notebook.

It must run windows 10: I can install it myself but if there are no drivers, I cannot install it. I run Linux in an OS box.

- At least 8GB RAM
- It should be able to contain my 1TB SSD
- Warranty is not a concern
- Around $2000 USD, not strict
- 15" screen or bigger
- 1920x1080 resolution or higher (horizontal/vertical may NOT be lower than 1920/1080!!)
- Weight is not a concern

I can also purchase in France or Germany.

Comment: Some questions: What interface does your SSD use? SATA, PCI-E mSATA or something else? Do you mean HiDPI scaling when you say "2 to 1 pixels"? (because I'm pretty sure you can turn that off) What specific software do you use? If it is typical programming stuff, you could probably get a weaker GPU. You might also like to consider an AIO or a Mini-ITX/other SFF PC, e.g. a NUC, which would also be portable (though you need power).

Comment: @Alpha3031 is is using SATA . GPU -> i want to be gaming with it as well once in a while. That's why host must be windows as well. NUC -> i'd need a screen. I am not sure why someone would buy a NUC when you can have a notebook? is it the price?

Comment: Why buy hardware in switzerland? Is it cheaper there? Compared to where?

Comment: @ThomasWeller colombia... colombia has a like 20% tax on all electronics that cost more than 1000 USD. And i think switzerland and USA are almost the same?

Comment: Well, 8% in Switzerland, but don't you need to pay the difference at the customs?

Comment: @Toskan You should be able to change the HiDPI scaling factor: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471

Comment: @ThomasWeller to bring in a personal used computer you pay customs? in what country? you ever traveled somewhere, brought your camera, and then paid customs for bringing your camera? ...

Comment: @Alpha3031 this is a tool to scale mac / window native apps. It is not related to the 2 to 1, physical pixels to css pixel that you will face when having a retina display on web pages. At least not to my understanding. Because I can use this scaling as well on windows, and it has no effect on the web page. Because it does not change the hardware. It just changes native apps to look a bit bigger or smaller. That is not related

Comment: Alienware is famous for gaming laptops.  Go there first.

Comment: @cybernard Alienware WAS famous for gaming laptops, now that they are owned by Dell, they are much less so..  You want a gaming laptop, go to Asus/MSI/Sager

Comment: @Toskan  You originally wrote that you cannot travel with a desktop?  Sure you can :P, you just get one of [these](http://www.cabelas.com/product/PELICAN-Elite-Vacationer-Luggage/1913131.uts?productVariantId=4039059&WT.tsrc=PPC&WT.mc_id=GoogleProductAds&WT.z_mc_id1=04051945&rid=20&gclid=Cj0KEQiAqdLDBRDD-b2sv6-i6MsBEiQAkT3wAsHJbNNIsbCJpIjuuBNoHJh6gGDhbvptsPvhhfKUUDwaArEp8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds), secure your case inside with straps and webbing, as well as securing the cards in a separate package, and you are all set

Comment: @NZKshatriya so i buy another suitcase for 500 dollars, pay the extra money to get it into the airplane, and the extra money to get it from and to the airport, build it together each time etc? dude... haha wtf :D

Comment: Well yeah, or you could ship it wherever you are going ahead of time....like golfers do with their clubs lol.  It is ludicrous, but people DO do it.  Especially those who go to major PC conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with the Acer Aspire V17 Nitro.

Screen  17.3 inch, 3840 x 2160 px

Processor   Intel Skylake Core i7-6700HQ CPU, quad-core 2.6 GHz (3.5 GHz TBoost)

Video   Intel HD 530 + Nvidia GTX 960M 4GB

Memory  16 GB DDR4 2133Mhz (2xDIMMs)

Storage 512 GB SSD + 1 TB 2.5″ HDD

Its lightweight Despite the its  960M It has a 512GB nvme SSD, 4k display and a damn 7hr battery life, since you are a programmer you might consider that, at a price around $1700. But smart would also be to wait for CES 2017 releases.

Comment: isnt acer pure garbage? sorry for the language, but they seem to be like hp a spec boost and all else sucks. Thats what i read from a repair man working at a computer store. Acer is just junk. What do you think about the ASUS G752VS-GC006T . I see no point going for gtx 960, it is already old

Comment: @Toskan Acer is not "garbage". This is a high end laptop, and it is a reputable company.

Also, what you are getting is a GTX 960**M**, which is mobile and worse than a GTX 960

Comment: He's a programmer not a  hardcore gamer. He needs the  battery life rather than graphics @Toskan

Comment: well but if you get a gaming notebook, you should not get an old graphic card that you can never upgrade.  And acer really does seem like junk, not only according to what I read, but as well according to reviews: http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/laptop-brand-ratings with a constant 5 years 8th rank or worse